# how convert string to int in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, integer

I obtain a string after use `number = sep[1].scan(/\w+/)` but later I need to compare number with other number. I known when I use `sep[1].scan(/\w+/)` I discard other symbols but how convert my string number into a real integer?

Comment: `String` has methods `to_i` to convert to `Integer`, and `to_f` to convert to `Float`.

Comment: Using `\w+` and `scan` to extract a single number seems odd. How do your strings look like and what's the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for this problem is: with regular expression; number is an array with length 1 so I need to convert number[0] to array, like this: `num_integer =number[0].to_i`

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written just captures a whole word which is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` any number of times.

`string.scan(/\w+/)` will scan for that word. But if you want to just extract numbers from the words, just use `string.scan(/\d+/)` and then convert using `.to_i`. If you scan using `\w+` and then if you call `.to_i`, two things can happen

#### Case 1: string starting with a number

In this case, for example `"879random"` will return `879` when `.to_i` is called over it. The `.to_i` method looks for numbers from the starting of the string. It doesn't capture randomly scattered numbers in a string. If the starting is not a number look at case 2.

#### Case 2: string not starting with a number

In this case, it will always return `0` no matter what your string is if it starts with a non-digit. For example, `"s729742384023041646891273948"` will return `0`. The method `.to_i` starts grouping digits from the start of the string until it finds a non-digit or till the end.

So it is better to use `.scan(/\d+/)` rather than `.scan(/\w+/)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure it is a valid number, you can use `Kernel#Integer` method. Otherwise it will raise an ArgumentError.

```rb
Integer("123")  # 123
Integer("123xyz")  # `Integer': invalid value for Integer(): "123xyz" (ArgumentError)
```